# Why won't my nav menu respect the CSS margin attributes?

Tags: html, css

As the title says. I can't seem to get my nav menu to respect the margin rules that I have set in the CSS. Is the "float: left;" property causing issues regarding the margins?

I have very limited knowledge with HTML/CSS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="description of the webpage">
  <meta name="keywords" content="keywords for the webpage">
  <meta name="author" content="your name and/or email here">

  <title>First Webpage</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #2b2b2b;
      font-family: ‘Arial Black’, Gadget, sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    /*------------------------------------NAV MENU---------------------------------------*/
    nav ul {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-family: ‘Arial Black’, Gadget, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-left: 35px;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #C63D0F;
      border-style: solid;
      border-size: 8px;
      border-color: #7E8F7C;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    nav li {
      border-right: 4px solid #7E8F7C;
      float: left;
    }
    nav li a {
      display: block;
      color: #FDF3E7;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav li a:hover {
      background-color: #3B3738;
    }
    /*------------------------------------NAV MENU---------------------------------------*/
    .education,
    .revlevant_work,
    .professional_experience,
    .skills,
    .activities {
      background-color: #3B3738;
      color: #FDF3E7;
      margin: 35px;
      padding: 15px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 8px;
      border-color: #7E8F7C;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main_content">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Video Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Image Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Personal</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div>

      <div class="education">
        <h1>Education</h1> 
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Ajax High School 2010 - 2014</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Garduated in 2014 from <b>Ajax High School</b> with a Ontario Secondary School Diploma.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>George Brown College 2016 - Current</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Currently enrolled in Computer Systems Technology (T147) at <b>George Brown College.</b>
            </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="revlevant_work">
        <h1>Relevant Course Work</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="professional_experience">
        <h1>Professional experience</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Salvation Army Thrift Store</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Aspect Logistics</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>All Maintenance Contractors</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Canadian Tire</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="skills">
        <h1>Skills</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Understanding of Computer Systems and the Operation of Software</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Communication Skills</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Adaptability/Flexibility</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Leadership/Management Skills</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="activities">
        <h1>Activities</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>Reading</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Video Games</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Art/Concept Art</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>


    <footer>
      <!-- edit/no content -->
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you use the `position` property with a value different than the default `static` you remove the element from the normal document flow. When you do this, margins are no longer affecting the flow of the document. That's why your other elements are not 'pushed' down. I recommend that you read [**this**](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the margin issues. Looks like the "position: fixed;" property isn't very friendly to work with.

Answer (score 0):

When the `position` property is used with a different value than the default `static`, the element is removed from the normal document flow.

When this is done, margins are no longer affecting the flow of the document. That's why the elements are not 'pushed' down. I recommend reading [**this**](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  font-family: ‘Arial Black’, Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}
main,
[role="main"] {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
/*------------------------------------NAV MENU---------------------------------------*/

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
nav {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
nav ul {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: ‘Arial Black’, Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #C63D0F;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: #7E8F7C;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav li {
  border-right: 4px solid #7E8F7C;
  float: left;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FDF3E7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #3B3738;
}
/*------------------------------------NAV MENU---------------------------------------*/

.education,
.revlevant_work,
.professional_experience,
.skills,
.activities {
  background-color: #3B3738;
  color: #FDF3E7;
  margin: 35px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: #7E8F7C;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Video Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Image Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Personal</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main id="main_content" role="main">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="education">
      <h1>Education</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Ajax High School 2010 - 2014</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Garduated in 2014 from <b>Ajax High School</b> with a Ontario Secondary School Diploma.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>George Brown College 2016 - Current</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Currently enrolled in Computer Systems Technology (T147) at <b>George Brown College.</b>
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="revlevant_work">
      <h1>Relevant Course Work</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p></p>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="professional_experience">
      <h1>Professional experience</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Salvation Army Thrift Store</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Aspect Logistics</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>All Maintenance Contractors</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Canadian Tire</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="skills">
      <h1>Skills</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Understanding of Computer Systems and the Operation of Software</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Communication Skills</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Adaptability/Flexibility</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Leadership/Management Skills</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="activities">
      <h1>Activities</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Reading</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Video Games</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Art/Concept Art</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <!-- edit/no content -->
</footer>
```

---

Make sure to read about semantic HTML too, some element tags were changed in the demo to guide you in the right direction. Here are some [**Frontend Guidelines**](https://github.com/bendc/frontend-guidelines).